# How to send notification from EJB container to web container in Java

Tags: java, jsf, web, ejb

I want to send notification from EJB container to Web container showing that something has occured on the service layer.
Basically my service layer is on EJB container and i get request from client on my web service and want to tell web container that some request has occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face same problem sometime ago and i done it using AJAX. i found that you cannot send notification from EJB container to web container rather you must explicitly check from web container by polling to EJB container. U can set a boolean variable whenever you get request at EJB container,  and check that variable value at Web container by pooling after sometime so if that boolean is true this mean that you have some notification and you can get that notification.
I have done this by above method hope this works for u

Comment: Can't believe there is no server push for that case. In the close future I wanted to implement something similar if it is possible. EJB->WEB->Client. Web to client is possible so I hope EJB to WEB is possible to.